# Get more product field value in Algolia json data

Tags: magento2, algolia

We are using Algolia extension for Magento 2. We added 2-3 field in the products, so we want to show the value of those fields on instant search result page. As we checking the view/frontend/templates/instant/hit.phtml is in use, we want to add the custom attributes to the JSON data so we can fetch those attributes value and show in listing page.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add new fields to Algolia product index if not already added. You can use one of the custom backend events. e.g. algolia_after_create_product_object

Once your fields are indexed properly (verify from Algolia account console), you should be able to get those in hit.phtml